# triangulation of a circle and the way to solve a problem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex, triangulation

Consider the circle $S^1$
 with multiplication given by the complex numbers.
Prove that the map $f(x) = x
^n$
, $n$ a positive integer, has degree $n$. What is the
degree of the map $g(x) = 1/x$.

This is exercise 25 of Croom's book "basic concepts in algebraic topology". I have not solved it yet.

My approach is that I triangulate the circle as follows: denote $a=(1,0),b=(-1,0),c=(0,1), d=(0,-1)$. The complex contains the 1-simplexes $(ab),(ac),(ad),(bc),(bd)$ and their faces. However, with this triangulation, I computed $H_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}^2$, which is wrong.

So could u explain why I was wrong, and how to solve the original problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place you went wrong was this:

The 1-simplexes should be $ac$, $cb$, $bd$, and $da$. The edge $ab$ is a diameter of the circle.

With that in hand, perhaps you can complete the problem yourself. One way to solve it is indeed to triangulate, although you'll probably want quite a lot more vertices to make that easier.

Comment: thank u. Can u explain why u think it would make the problem easier if we have more vertices?

Personally, I think these 4 would do it since $x^n$ and $1/x$ map these four to these four, hence simplicial maps.

Comment: Your complex was a circle with one diameter included, or, drawn with straight lines, it's a pair of triangles that share one edge. The first homology of this object is, in face $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$.

Comment: tks. I just realize that and delete the question :)). What about my first ques?

Comment: As for your map: even for $n = 2$, it's not simplicial, for the images of $a$ and $c$ end up being $a$ and $b$, and while $ac$ is an edge, $ab$ is not. You'll need to triangulate the domain and codomain with different numbers of vertices to make this all work out (if you're approaching it the way you seem to be).

Comment: wow, seems like much more work than I thought. Thank u